# changing a directory

Tags: directory

In terminal I want to change a directory to something with a # sign in it.  For example #filename.chat and can't seem to remember how to do this.  From the command line I think it is suppose to be `cd /filename.chat/` but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the best way to do this is to use the `\` escape character. The method that @Shauna suggests will work in this case but has limitations. For example if the filename has quotes in it what do you do? this?:

```
cd "some """Movie Title""""
```

No, that would be silly. You would do this:

```
cd some\ \"Movie\ Title\"
```

The next character after the escape `\` is not interpretted by the shell. This is what we want.

**There are three methods of escaping character in bash.**

- **Double quotes**

Least powerful method. Preserves literal value except for dollar sign, backticks, and backslash.(tldp.org)

- **Single quotes**

Most powerful. Hides all special characters.

- **Backslash**

Similar to single quotes, but only hides one character at a time.

A good resource for this is [TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say @Shauna 's method is incorrect, but it's important to be aware of the limits of the method. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Jason I edited my post

Answer (score 3):

Just put quotes around it, like this:

```
cd "#filename.chat"
```

If you lead with a `/`, then it's going to look for the file or folder in the root directory (just fyi).

Comment: Alternatively escape the `#` by writing `\#filename.chat`